# Wikipedia API search -- Retrieve same index of each array with forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, foreach, wikipedia

I'm working on a project for freeCodeCamp and I've been stuck on this part all day. I'm pulling data from the Wikipedia API and I'm able to work with it, yet I'm not sure how the syntax should look for what I'm trying to achieve. Here is a link to an example of the data I'm working with. [Wikipedia API Search](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=coffee&format=jsonfm&callback=?).

Now, in my HTML I have a bootstrap modal that appears after the user inputs something into a form, with a listed group inside with the returned data from the search.

This is the code I have so far.

```
$(document).ready(function () {


 $('#searchForm').on('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#wikiSearch').modal('show');
   var usersearch = document.getElementById('userinput').value;
   var apiURL = "https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?
   action=opensearch&search=" 
   + usersearch + "&format=json&callback=?";

$.ajax({
  url: apiURL,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: 'json',
  type: 'GET',
  success: function (data) {
    data[1].forEach(function(item) {
      $('#results').append("<tr><td><a href='#'>"+item+"</a></td></tr>")
    });
    data[2].forEach(function(item) {
      $('#brief').append("<tr><td>"+item+"</td></tr>")
    })
  }
   });
  });
 });
```

For each group in my modal of my HTML I want to display 1 result from the search. I figured I would be able to use a nested forEach but it's not returning the results I wanted. I've tried using map, and also tried creating a long nested for loop and feel like I might be doing more harm than good when it comes to learning since I'm only getting confused now lol. Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show the first row from the search results use the first key of the nested array:

```
$('#results').append("<tr><td><a href='#'>" + data[1][0] + "</a></td></tr>")
$('#brief').append("<tr><td>" + data[2][0] + "</td></tr>")
```

Don't forget to add a check for the possible `undefined` value inside the `data` array.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! So I never even needed the forEach method in the first place.. -___- lol thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @nicer00ster. If my answer helped you solve the problem, you should [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: Gotcha! Mind if I message you to ask another question related to this one?

Comment: I'll help if I'm online.